# what is the difference between Dev containers and Docker extension in VScode ? Also Dev Enviroments on Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-desktop

I'm new to Docker, I want to use it with my VSCode but I found 2 extensions which are Docker and Dev Containers. To me, they're pretty similar that I couldn't find much differences between them.
Can anyone elaborate on their differences in terms of functionality and use cases?
Thank y'all.

Furthermore, I installed Docker Desktop. In its UI, there's a tab for creating Dev Environments and it lets me choose VScode as Editor for working with containers. This even confuses me more.

Comment: People often use search engines to find evaluation guides and/or product manuals on such products and then play with them to see the differences, which can take hours and even days. You might do so and come back with your own answer.